# Replacing special characters in text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, regex, find-and-replace, parsing

I would normally use Perl and regex for this, but to simplify portability between Windows computers, I am hoping to accomplish the following using PowerShell instead:

A CSV file containing incorrectly encoded characters needs to be parsed and corrected. The natural language in question is Norwegian.

Output from a third party system substitutes the characters æ ø å with ‘ › †

As I am not comfortable with PowerShell at all at the present, I was hoping someone could mock up a small script which reads a source text file from disk and outputs it into another.

Thank you

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126603/powershell-or-batch-find-and-replace-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appleoddity's referenced article covers what I am looking for. Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126603/powershell-or-batch-find-and-replace-characters